# Jquery Dialog Box not subbmitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button on my form like :

```
<input type="button" id="filter" name="filter" value="Filter ResKB" />
```

I also have a jquery to popup a dialog box like :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filter").click(function(){
        $( "#dialogg" ).dialog();
    });
});
</script>
```

This displays the contents of my div tag named dialogg, here is the div tag with a form :

```
<div id="dialogg" title="Filter Records" style="display: none">
<form name="filt" id="filt" method="post" action="../ib/filter.php">
<p>Please select the values that are to be filtered.<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="id" name="id">Issue ID</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="sum" name="sum">Summary</input><br>
<input type="button" id="fil" name="fil" value="Filter"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Now clicking on the filter button inside the dialog box does not redirect me to the desired page. How can i do this? Also i want to fetch the value in a php variable what script can i run for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
type=button
```

to

```
type=submit
```

> **type=button** will not submit your form and it will work like button clickable. Where **type=submit** will submit your form at desire action will mentioned in action.

Comment: can u help make the dialog box non resizable and non movable?

Comment: You can ask new question with your problem, so someone will help you.